# sniffing visited sites and save to a file

Tags: java, http, url, browser, sniffer

I want to log http trafic in some pc connected to my network, in order to know what sites have been visited by the user. This program will run in a company maybe to check that worker don't go to sites extra-job maybe to stats. I need only to know what pc surfed what site at what hour, no other infos.

I surfed the net an googled for hours not finding anything useful to me. I tried wireshark, but is too complicated and can't be run as daemon (as I know, maybe I am wrong) and that window is huge.

I tried to bind a ServerSocket to the 80 port, with no success, no data seems to reach my socket. Same result with Socket (binded to 80 localhost) Is there any class that allow me to insert between safari (or any other browser) and the port?

[before I was asked to do this, the company used a keyboard sniffer for a few days. But the privacy in that way was zero and obviously that wasn't the right solution.]

Any idea?
P.s. the program is not going to be "secret", workers knows about it but the need is that it can't be stopped by non-admin people.

A solution in java is preferred, because it's the only language I know.

Comment: Run user internet access through a proxy, there are many. Remind me not to work there.

Comment: I think the owner of the company want to allow "moderate" access to non-job-related sites, because I tried to tell him about proxies and he told me they're to restrictive

Comment: Proxies were too restrictive and this company was keylogging their employees?

Comment: That makes zero sense, it's precisely what you've asked for. A proxy doesn't have to restrict access, it can just log requests, then someone with too much time on their hands can snoop.

Comment: sorry, I started this question the wrong way. the company was requesting a log on visited sites, I suppose to avoid not autorized sites, the answer you gave me make me understand that maybe they want to know the sites not just to disallow them (and maybe I was supposing wrong). In fact the keylogging was only (as they told me) a few days try (for obvious reason of privacy). They explicitly want an url logger. And this what I am asking for. I will edit the question in a moment

Comment: @Dave ok, writing this you demonstrate me that I don't really know what a proxy is and how to use it for my task. If you think is the right way. can you explain how to use it or just link some help? I was reading about transparent proxy, is this the one i need? I need also a dedicated pc as server?

Comment: Do you want to write a program to perform these functions, or are you asking if we know of a program that already does this?

Comment: I prefer to write one, for improve my skill, but also because I need a very simple program, and the ones I found are very large (beautiful indeed, but too much complicated). If I want to be paid to this thing It's honest that the work is made by me, and not just installed and also the need of a simple program is because on the other side of the terminal there can be a not-trained person.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your last comment (you should update your question btw) I understand you need something to log all http traffic.

You must understand that to do so easily you need to be in the middle between the private network and internet, likely with a linux firewall doing NAT for private network computers.

If you are Ok with running non java software then you can use the software urlsnarf from [dsniff](http://monkey.org/~dugsong/dsniff/) for what you want. You can run it and leave it in the background logging, you can filter also by port or ip.

Most distributions already have a package called dsniff which includes the urlsnarf command.

For basic start:

```
urlsnarf -n -i eth0
```

That will start logging to stdout all url's on tcp port 80, 8080 or 3128. If you want to store a capture for later visualization (e.g. with wireshark) you can use `-p` option.

If you ask me, I think you are doing it the wrong way, you should put a transparent proxy and just deny access to "not authorized" sites instead of recording every http url requested. Otherwise you are breaching people privacy and depending on the country it may be even illegal.

Setting up a server for NAT it's not difficult, you just need a linux PC with two network cards, one firewall software like [aifw](http://rocky.eld.leidenuniv.nl/joomla/) or [ipmasq](http://www.bbassett.net/ipmasq/), with this you already can prevent access to websites by blocking their IP's. If you also want to mess with http traffic packets data you need a transparent proxy ([not a reverse proxy](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/ReverseProxy)), the most popular is [Squid](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/).

I would recommend to check out [SquidGuard](http://www.squidguard.org/) if you go for Squid.

If you insist in coding one yourself besides warnings lefts on comments, without a doubt you should use [jpcap library](http://netresearch.ics.uci.edu/kfujii/Jpcap/doc/), check the [examples section](http://netresearch.ics.uci.edu/kfujii/Jpcap/doc/samples.html) where there's code already you can use to start quickly.

Good luck!

Comment: Excuse me, I did not understood you wanted the solution to be done in Java, do you need the sniffing software to be done with Java?

Comment: thank you for the large answer. Fortunately I can refactor all the net of that company, because they bought a new internal program from a software house and need to re-install all the net, so I think there will be no problem to add a computer between the private and the internet, good tip. There will be a written consent, signed by each employee, so no legal problem. I'm starting to following the last paragraph of your answer, it's just install and go or there is something else that need to be coded?

Comment: It depends on your background, setting up a firewall to do NAT (not transparent proxy but just provide internet) it's pretty easy, you just need to configure your both IP's and tell any of those softwares which interface is internet and which private network. Squid it's a little more trickier but it's not rocket science. Keep in mind that anyway be it NAT or proxied you will be in the middle, so **if your installation fails all company employees es will be offline so I would strongly recommend you to read the manual of whatever software you use in such a project**.

Comment: read my last comment at the first answer about the code and motivations (Yes the code is JAVA, i don't know C) I don't understand this " you just need to configure your both IP's". I imagine that all you said is only to explain how to set a NAT, but use a transparent proxy is more difficult? I need only http, it's the same using a NAT?

Comment: If you want to code a sniffer application for http traffic, you just need a server doing NAT. If server it's going to have two network interfaces,  you will need to configure both interfaces with your ISP provided IP and private interface with the IP that will act as gateway for all your LAN machines. The good side of sniffing only http instead of proxying is that it's passive and if your code crash traffic will keep flowing anyway. With all my respect, I think you should read more about basic networking if you want your customer to be happy. Example: sniffing won't allow you to log httpS.

Answer (score 0):

This thread is almost 9 years, but if incase someone is still looking for answers on this.....

Take a look at this
https://superuser.com/questions/52181/how-to-track-websites-that-have-been-visited

Create a command by retrieving list of visited files and save it by .txt, save it to your db and voila. you have achieve tracking of sites each pc.

Please check this code using java to download/view and purge(delete cache) visited sites list:

> ```
> > import java.io.IOException;
> > 
> > public class DNS_Actions {
> >     public void RetrieveDNS(){
> >         try {
> >             Process p = Runtime
> >                             .getRuntime()
> >                             .exec("cmd /min start cmd.exe /K \" cd "+System.getProperty("user.dir")+" && ipconfig /displaydns >
> > lists.txt\"");
> >         } catch (IOException e) {
> >             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
> >             e.printStackTrace();
> >         } 
> >     }
> >     public void purgeDNS(){
> >         try {
> >             Process p = Runtime
> >                             .getRuntime()
> >                             .exec("cmd /min start cmd.exe /K \" ipconfig /flushdns\"");
> >         } catch (IOException e) {
> >             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
> >             e.printStackTrace();
> >         } 
> >     }
> >     public static void main(String[] args){
> >         new DNS_Actions().RetrieveDNS();
> >     } }
> ```